# How to write vectorization code for 2 matrix

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices like this:

```
gt = [30 40 20 40] and
de = [32 42 20 40; 34 12 20 40; 36 84 20 40]
```

I want to calculate the overlap area between `gt` and `3 rows` of `de` respectively and the overlap is calculated by a function I write myself. Then I want to store the result in a new column vector like

```
result = [result1; result2; result3].
```

Could you tell me how to write a vectorization codes to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you define overlap?

Comment: The answer highly depends on how you define overlap. So you should post that function

Comment: oh yes I forgot to mention the overlap: function val = iou(gt,de)
    iarea = rectint(gt,de);
    val = iarea/(gt(3)*gt(4) + de(3)*de(4) - iarea);
      
end

Comment: Don't put code in comments, click the "edit" link below your question and update the question itself instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectorization can only happen inside the overlap function. The only thing you can do outside it is replicate the vector gt, using repmat or bsxfun. You don't explain how the overlap function works. I suppose it has to do with co-ordinates, so I give an example for euclidean distance which works in a similar logic.

If you had to calculate the distance between point gt = [1 2] and points de = [5 6; 10 12; 0 -1] you would define

```
 function result = dist(x, y)
  result = sum(sqrt((x(:,1) - y(:,1)).^2 + (x(:,2) - y(:,2)).^2), 2)
```

and you would call it replicating the gt vector

```
 dist(de, repmat(gt, 3, 1))
```

Alternatively, you could use bsxfun instead of repmat, which might have better performance (depending on various factors)

The key to vectorizing is performing operations column-wise (in this specific case it could be vectorized even further, however I am writing it this way to emphasize the column-wise operations)